# How Do I Get The Zombie Loadout?

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

I have been playing COD AW for a while now, I only have the zombie knee pads and the zombie exo. How do I get the rest?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this website](http://gametipcenter.com/call-of-duty-advanced-warfare-unlock-zombie-armor-skin), there are a number of things you must do to unlock everything:

> - Zombie Gloves – Survive 50 rounds on any of the maps in Tier 1
> - Zombie Kneepads – Survive 50 rounds on any of the maps in Tier 1
> - Zombie Exo – Survive 75 rounds on any of the maps in Tier 2
> - Zombie Boots – Survive 75 rounds on any of the maps in Tier 2
> - Zombie Pants – Survive 100 rounds on any of the maps in Tier 3
> - Zombie Loadout (Chest) – Max out the Armor stat (level 10) at the Armor Exo Station
> - Zombie Helmet – Max out the Weapon Proficiency stat (level 10) at the Weapon Exo Station
> - Zombie Shirt – Survive at least one round on all Exo Survival maps

Lastly to unlock the skin:

> To unlock the Zombie Skin, you need to complete the secret zombie round in Exo Survival